# error: cannot find symbol method getDownloadUrl()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm still a beginner in programming. I'm developing an application for a college job. However, I came across this mistake. I do not know how I can fix it. This problem:

> error: cannot find symbol method `getDownloadUrl()`

How can I solve this error?

Here is my code:

```
package com.valcirjr98.logindj;


$public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int CHOOSE_IMAGE = 101;

    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
    EditText editText;

    Uri uriProfileImage;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    String profileImageUrl;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDisplayName);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewVerified);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showImageChooser();
            }
        });

        loadUserInformation();

        findViewById(R.id.buttonSave).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                saveUserInformation();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    }

    private void loadUserInformation() {
        final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (user != null) {
            if (user.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
                Glide.with(this)
                        .load(user.getPhotoUrl().toString())
                        .into(imageView);
            }

            if (user.getDisplayName() != null) {
                editText.setText(user.getDisplayName());
            }

            if (user.isEmailVerified()) {
                textView.setText("Email Verified");
            } else {
                textView.setText("Email Not Verified (Click to Verify)");
                textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        user.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Verification Email Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }


    private void saveUserInformation() {


        String displayName = editText.getText().toString();

        if (displayName.isEmpty()) {
            editText.setError("Name required");
            editText.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (user != null && profileImageUrl != null) {
            UserProfileChangeRequest profile = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                    .setDisplayName(displayName)
                    .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse(profileImageUrl))
                    .build();

            user.updateProfile(profile)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Profile Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CHOOSE_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            uriProfileImage = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uriProfileImage);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                uploadImageToFirebaseStorage();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void uploadImageToFirebaseStorage() {
        StorageReference profileImageRef =
                FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("profilepics/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        if (uriProfileImage != null) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            profileImageRef.putFile(uriProfileImage)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            profileImageUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menuLogout:

                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));

                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void showImageChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Profile Image"), CHOOSE_IMAGE);
    }

}
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask.TaskSnapshot - can not see the method you want

Comment: No... You dont add random lyrics when your post is too short, you need to make it longer and add more detail, theres a reason why its there

Comment: @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            profileImageUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        }

Answer (score 0):

```
profileImageRef.putFile(uriProfileImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
               profileImageUrl= taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
            }
        });
```

*

This method worked for me.

```
 profileImageRef.putFile(uriProfileImage).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful() && task != null) {
                    profileImageUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
              }
                }
        });
```

Try this!

Comment: @ValcirJúnior  did you try the second method with addOnCompleteListener?  I am using the second method and it works perfectly fine.