# getDownloadUri() in Firebase Storage is deprecated or cannot resolve

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Okay so I already read what's in the doc but unfortunately there's no sample about the new way of getting download Uri. How am I supposed to get it after uploading a image file? Another thing is that I saw some example using Task here in stack but what is the essence of changing the way of getting a download uri? I am trying to do it but now it seems too complicated. I don't really understand why they deprecate it and change it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50660975/firebase-storage-getdownloadurl-method-cant-be-resolved, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554548/error-cannot-find-symbol-method-getdownloadurl-of-type-com-google-firebase-st, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594843/error-cannot-find-symbol-method-getdownloadurl

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how am I supposed to get it if I use UploadTask instead of StorageReference like this  mThumbnailTask = mStorageRef.child(getResources().getString(R.string.userProfilePic) + "/-thumbnails").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()+".jpg")
                                        .putBytes(thumbData);

Comment: You *are* using a reference. E.g. `StorageReference ref = mStorageRef.child(getResources().getString(R.string.userProfilePic) + "/-thumbnails").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()+".jpg")`. Then call `ref.putBytes(...` to start uploading and `ref.getDownloadUrl(...` to get the download URL.

Comment: Thanks anyway I am able to get the download uri with UploadTask using Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(taskSnapshot.getMetadata()).getReference()).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) { }